# Получить id из массива, занеся результат в новый массив

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется такая конструкция:

```
foreach($secondsArray as $resul)
{
    $id = $resul['id']; 
    $url = "https://site.com/api/project/$id/information";
    $get_all_engines = connectToSite($url, $token);
    $temp = [];
       foreach($get_all_engines as $arr){
           $temp[] = $arr['id'];
       }
}
```

Которая выводит id в таком порядке:

```
Array ( [0] => 70557 [1] => 70558 [2] => 70559 ) 
Array ( [0] => 70648 [1] => 70649 [2] => 70650 ) 
Array ( [0] => 70661 [1] => 70662 [2] => 70663 ) 
Array ( [0] => 70735 )
```

Как получить ID всех записей, и записать в новый ассоциативный массив

Ожидаемый результат

```
Array ( [0] => 70557 [1] => 70558 [2] => 70559 [3] => 70648 [4] => 70649 [5] => 70650 *[6] => 70661 [7] => 70662 [8] => 70663 )
```

Исходный код массива: $get_all_engines

```
array(3) { 
[0]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(70557) ["engine_id"]=> int(1) ["engine_zone_id"]=> int(257) ["engine_zone_region_id"]=> int(1) ["check_interval"]=> int(1) } 
[1]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(70558) ["engine_id"]=> int(3) ["engine_zone_id"]=> int(1338) ["engine_zone_region_id"]=> int(1002) ["check_interval"]=> int(1) } 
[2]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(70559) ["engine_id"]=> int(8) ["engine_zone_id"]=> int(1633) ["engine_zone_region_id"]=> int(3931) ["check_interval"]=> int(1) } } array(3) { 
[0]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(70648) ["engine_id"]=> int(1) ["engine_zone_id"]=> int(257) ["engine_zone_region_id"]=> int(1) ["check_interval"]=> int(1) } 
[1]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(70649) ["engine_id"]=> int(3) ["engine_zone_id"]=> int(1338) ["engine_zone_region_id"]=> int(1002) ["check_interval"]=> int(1) } 
[2]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(70650) ["engine_id"]=> int(8) ["engine_zone_id"]=> int(1633) ["engine_zone_region_id"]=> int(3931) ["check_interval"]=> int(1) } } array(3) { 
[0]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(70661) ["engine_id"]=> int(1) ["engine_zone_id"]=> int(257) ["engine_zone_region_id"]=> int(1) ["check_interval"]=> int(1) } 
[1]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(70662) ["engine_id"]=> int(3) ["engine_zone_id"]=> int(1338) ["engine_zone_region_id"]=> int(1002) ["check_interval"]=> int(1) } 
[2]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(70663) ["engine_id"]=> int(8) ["engine_zone_id"]=> int(1633) ["engine_zone_region_id"]=> int(3931) ["check_interval"]=> int(1) } } array(1) { 
[0]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(70735) ["engine_id"]=> int(3) ["engine_zone_id"]=> int(1338) ["engine_zone_region_id"]=> int(1002) ["check_interval"]=> int(1) } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вам уже публиковал решение для такой структуры массива *(повтор)* :

```
<?php

/*
Array
(
    [0] => 70557
    [1] => 70558
    [2] => 70559
    [3] => 70560
)
*/

$array = array(
    array(
        "id" => 70557,
        "value" => 1,
        "zone" => 257,
        "region" => 1,
        "check" => 1
    ),

    array(
        "id" => 70558,
        "value" => 3,
        "zone" => 1338,
        "region" => 1002,
        "check" => 1
    ),

    array(
        "id" => 70559,
        "value" => 8,
        "zone" => 1633,
        "region" => 3931,
        "check" => 1
    ),

    array(
        "id" => 70560,
        "value" => 9,
        "zone" => 1644,
        "region" => 3932,
        "check" => 1
    )
);

$temp = [];

foreach ($array as $arr) {
    $temp[] = $arr['id'];
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($temp); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: @Андрей Суворов структуру результирующего массива вы в первом посту не указали, поэтому я написал наугад.

Comment: Да, верно, чтобы все id записать в один массив

Comment: @Андрей Суворов отредактировал свой ответ. Если он является решением, то отметьте его галкой.

Comment: то что было у вас закомментировано, было правильным выводом, это было то что я хотел

Comment: @Андрей Суворов тогда не понимаю, в чём проблема? Тот код, который был под комментарием, как раз и формировал такой массив. В чём проблема у вас?

Comment: @Андрей Суворов я понял, что вы хотели _(наверное)_ Свой пост с ответом я отредактировал.

Comment: я хочу объединить значение всех массивов в один массив, и указать им новые ключи

Comment: @Андрей Суворов напишите в вашем первом посту _(отредактируйте его)_ структуру нового массива, а то мы так долго будем ходить кругами.

Comment: сейчас переделаю

Comment: @АндрейСуворов я же вам уже публиковал решение для такой структуры массива... Отредактировал свой ответ.

Comment: Дело в том, что этот цикл вложенный, есть поверхностный цикл

Comment: @АндрейСуворов вот об этом надо было сразу говорить в первом посту. Соберите массив $arrays в первом цикле, а потом этот массив обработайте вторым циклом _(из моего примера)_

Comment: Обновил информацию.

Comment: что подразумевает сейчас глядя на обновлённую информацию, собрать массив в первом цикле?

Comment: @АндрейСуворов посмотрите пример:  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c22c304eb5ed9a3330e81335a0e5b24ed8655d1d

Comment: посмотрел, с задачей уже справился, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($arrays as $key=>$array){
    $temp[$key] = $array['id'];
$temp[$key] = $array['value'];
$temp[$key] = $array['zone'];
$temp[$key] = $array['region'];
$temp[$key] = $array['check'];
}
```

Примерно так

Answer (score 0):

В итоге я переместил объявляемый цикл до всех циклов, и получил желанный результат.

Вот мелочь, а сколько время отняло.